# Export Flash Builder 4 project for Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm working on Flash Builder 4 and want to export a flex project so my colleague, with Flex 3, can open it. Unfortunately, exporting a .fxp file doesn't work with Flex 3. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks for any useful info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could:

1. Place it in a common svn repository and check it out through subclipse.
2. Zip the actual file structure (assuming you aren't doing anything too crazy in .flexProperties et al, this should work fine). Then simply import project from the file system. An `fxp` is basically a glorified `zip` anyway, so this shouldn't be terribly difficult.
3. Copy the files directly (Offers almost 0 benefit over zipping, but it is an option).